# How do I make the stuff inside a \defbeamertemplate* be top-aligned?

Tags: beamer, templates, frame-title

I'm specifying a `\defbeamertemplate*{title page}{xyz}[1][]{}` for the title page. However it appears to be aligned on the bottom or the centre. If I add longer titles and they line-break the header decoration (which is defined inside the `title page` because a title page doesn't usually have `\frametitle`) moves up and down. But I need it to stay fixed on one particular position.

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[presentation,english]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title[Scientific LaTeX]{abc}
\title[Scientific LaTeX]{The science of using LaTeX to present the most awesome stuff in science.}
\author{Prof. Sciencemaster}
\subtitle{Chapter 47} 
\subtitle{Chapter 47: Adjusting the flux capacitor in sub-lightspeed without Fusion-knobs}
\date{\today}

\defbeamertemplate*{title page}{bla}[1][t]
{
  \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}%
    \hspace{\dimexpr0.5\textwidth-0.5\paperwidth\relax}%
    \hspace{5pt}%
      \begin{minipage}{\paperwidth}%
        \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\paperwidth-1cm\relax}%
          \vskip1em\par%
          {\usebeamerfont{title}\color{blue}\inserttitle}%
          \ifx\insertsubtitle\empty%
          \else%
          \par%
          {\usebeamerfont{subtitle}\color{red}\insertsubtitle}%
          \fi%
          \par%
          {\usebeamerfont{author}\color{green}\insertauthor}%
        \end{minipage}%
      \end{minipage}%
  \end{minipage}%
}

\begin{document}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}[bla]
\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I basically want everything in that box to be top aligned, so I can build the page up from the top.

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @samcarter: Well it is spread over several `.sty`s so I'm not sure how to provide a minimal example. I'll try to come up with something.

Comment: @samcarter: There's a simple example, that shows a beamer template `bla`. I tried saying `[t]` but that didn't help. I suspect it's very simple, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can give optional arguments to the minipage, exspecially the `inner position`

```
\begin{minipage}[outer position][height][inner position]{width}
    ...
\end{minipage}
```

Some simplified version of your example:

```
\documentclass[presentation,english]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title[Scientific LaTeX]{abc}
\author{Prof. Sciencemaster}
\subtitle{Chapter 47} 
\date{\today}

\defbeamertemplate*{title page}{bla}[1][t]{%
    \begin{minipage}[t][\paperheight][t]{\dimexpr\paperwidth-1cm\relax}%
        \vskip1em\par%
    {\usebeamerfont{title}\color{blue}\inserttitle}%
    \ifx\insertsubtitle\empty%
    \else%
    \par%
    {\usebeamerfont{subtitle}\color{red}\insertsubtitle}%
    \fi%
    \par%
    {\usebeamerfont{author}\color{green}\insertauthor}%
  \end{minipage}%
}

\begin{document}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}[bla]
\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\title[Scientific LaTeX]{The science of using LaTeX to present the most awesome stuff in science.}
\subtitle{Chapter 47: Adjusting the flux capacitor in sub-lightspeed without Fusion-knobs}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[bla]
\begin{frame}
    \titlepage
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Comment: That sounds like a remarkably simple solution. It appears to do the trick in my minimal example. I'll give it a shot in the proper one, but it should work there as well. Thank you!